# How to encrypt a message written in a file entered by the user?

Tags: c++, string, encryption

```
        required.get(c);
    }
    cout << "The encryption is over";
    required.close();
    destined.close();
}
```

This program should encrypt/decrypt a message in a file, that the user should mention. It should have 3 functions, one to check the existence of the input file, the second should encrypt/decrypt each character and one to encrypt/decrypt the whole file. The thing is that the it keeps saying "The file does not exist". I don't know how to read it. Second problem is that the function to encrypt (encFile) does not work.

Comment: `required.open(infile.c+str())` is not valid syntax. Also, have you checked that the file actually *does* exist somewhere on your computer?

Comment: It's because the condition in `while(required.fail())` in your `checkExistingFile()` function never changes.

Comment: Also, "the function to encrypt does not work" doesn't tell us much about the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "never changes", can you explain more please?

Comment: You have two encryption functions. Which one doesn't work? What exactly is not working?

Comment: @user3379047 _'explain more please?'_ Do you see any statement inside the while loop, that changes the state of your `required` `ifstream` instance??

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ no. What should I do?

Comment: @user3379047 _'What should I do?'_ call `required.open(infile.c_str())` again after a new filename was entered to `infile`.

Comment: @user3379047 I'd appreciate an upvote if that helped :) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did try to "upvote" but it said it requires 15 rep. But as as I reach 15 I'll vote, no worries :) , one last question please, you said "and return false then" where would "return false;" be? Inside while or outside of it? Sorry to bother you again

Comment: THX for accepting. _'where would "return false;" be?'_ It should be inside the `while` loop, to _break out_ from it. Just have an appropriate condition to check after input, e.g. `if(inFile.empty()) { return false; }`.

Comment: I solved the problem and now the program is working, thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The thing is that the it keeps saying "The file does not exist". I don't know how to read it.

To fix this behavior change your `checkExistingFile()` function as follows:

```
 bool  checkExistingFile(string& inFile)
 {
      ifstream required;
      required.open(inFile.c_str());
      while(required.fail())
      {
           cout<< "The file does not exist, please enter another file " <<
                  "(leave empty to abort)"<< endl;
           cin >> inFile;
           if(infile.empty()) { return false; }
           required.open(inFile.c_str());
      }

      return true;
 }
```

May be you should consider to give the user a chance to break the loop (e.g. giving an empty file name), and return `false` then.

As others and you yourself mentioned there, are other problems with your code, I don't answer here.